# Listview Trouble - Tooltip Needed

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tooltip

I am building a WPF application in C# using VS2010

I have a listview that contains items from a database , and each item contains a field called (Name) and another field called (Time) .

Back in the database , each item has a third field called (Description) too ...

Now what I want is :
When I choose an item from the listview , a tooltip is shown and it contains the data from the third field ..

How can I have various tooltips on one listview - one tooltip for each item - ??
How can I deal with my database ??

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the Tooltip for a ListViewItem can be done like this

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```