# Tooltip on Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tooltip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set tooltip for a ListviewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730931/how-to-set-tooltip-for-a-listviewitem)

I am converting a Windows Forms application to WPF. I am very new to WPF.

In my application I have a listview. When the user moves the mouse to the items present in the listview I want to show the tooltip text for the highlighted item.

How to do this in WPF?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to set tooltip for a ListviewItem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730931/how-to-set-tooltip-for-a-listviewitem) and [Listview Trouble - Tooltip Needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184427/listview-trouble-tooltip-needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via binding:

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Content}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```